# Armstrong number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have to find whether the number is Armstrong or not. In result it's showing all the numbers are Armstrong Number. Please help me to find the error.

```js
var num1 = parseInt(prompt('Enter your number'))
var sum = 0
var num = num1
while (num1 > 0) {
  var r = num1 % 10
  var sum = sum + r * r * r
  var num1 = num1 / 10
}
if (num == sum) {
  document.write('It is an Armstrong Number')
} else {
  document.write('It is not an Armstrong Number')
}
```

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/javascript/examples/armstrong-number

Comment: Don't re-declare `var` when operating on a preexisting variable

Comment: `num1 / 10` should be `Math.floor(num1 / 10)`

Comment: Ok, I have tried now it's showing it is not an Armstrong Number for all.

Comment: Ok, great now it's working thankyou so much @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

When you divide by 10, you need to discard the fraction so you'll just process the digits. You can use `Math.floor()` to do this.

```js
var num1 = parseInt(prompt('Enter your number'))
var sum = 0
var num = num1
while (num1 > 0) {
  var r = num1 % 10
  sum = sum + r * r * r
  num1 = Math.floor(num1 / 10)
}
if (num == sum) {
  document.write('It is an Armstrong Number')
} else {
  document.write('It is not an Armstrong Number')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you were trying to go about this, so I rewrote it a little. Basically you ask for a number in a string, `split()` the string into an array, and loop through the array with `forEach()`, adding each character as a number to the power of three with `Math.pow()`:

```js
let num = prompt('Enter your number')
let sum = 0
let pow
num.split('').forEach(char => {
  pow = Math.pow(parseInt(char), 3)
  sum += pow
})

if (parseInt(num) === sum) {
  document.write('It is an Armstrong Number')
} else {
  document.write('It is not an Armstrong Number')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code only checks 3 digits numbers and it fails on 4 digits (like 8204). I recommend below codes;

```js
let num = prompt('Enter your number')
let sum = 0
let power = num.length;
let pow
num.split('').forEach(char => {
  pow = Math.pow(parseInt(char), power)
  sum += pow
})

if (parseInt(num) === sum) {
  document.write('It is an Armstrong Number')
} else {
  document.write('It is not an Armstrong Number')
}
```